# How to find where rogue writing to stderr happens in Golang program?

Tags: go

I've got a rather large Golang program with rather many dependencies. Somewhere, someone writes rogue data to stderr.

I want to find where this write is occurring so I can remove it.

I know I can intercept stderr using `Dup2` and Pipes, so I can *detect* the write as it occurs; but this does not let me get a stack from the goroutine doing the write.

In other languages, I'd set `os.Stderr` to a custom File with a hooked `Write` function. Is there a way to do this in Go that I'm not aware of? If not, what would be a good way to find where this method call is happening?

Comment: Have you tried? It would be helpful to know if the problem package captures `os.Stderr` before you could even re-assign it.

Comment: I've tried the Dup2 thing - and that works but has the noted issue. Intercepting os.Stderr is my issue, I'm not sure how I would do it in a way that lets me capture a stack trace. 

Although I just realized I can change os.File#Write directly in my copy of the stdlib.. and it looks like that might work!

Comment: There is an option use `runtime/trace` and trace viewer to find syscalls (writing to Stderr included) which has a trace stack. Problem is, when it is a large program, it would be quite a bit works to find it.

Comment: I thought that you might be able to take advantage of [epipecheck](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/95d4e6158b4199e1eee957e2c8c934d2cb86c35e/src/os/file.go#L153) by duping a broken pipe into stderr, but that does not give you a stacktrace.  Changing the File.Write source is the way to go.  You should write that as an answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept logging by providing `io.Writer` to [log.SetOutput](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#SetOutput). There you can simply check if string that is being loged is what you need to trace and write stacktrace to the delegated wrapped writer.

Here is an example
playground: https://play.golang.org/p/2bClt2JBuFs

Please note that getting current stacktrace is not free, it causes stop-of-the-world and can drastically slow your application down. In case you have an application that produces a high volume of logs I would recommend limit amount of data being traced (e.g. trace only first match or N times per second/minute)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "runtime/debug"
)

func main() {
    log.SetOutput(NewLogInterceptor(LogInterceptionCheck{Pattern: ".*Some.*", Description: "with 'Some' substring"}))
    f1()
    log.Println("message that is not traced")
}

func f1() {
    log.Println("Some message")
}



type LogInterceptor struct {
    target *os.File
    checks []LogInterceptionCheck
}

type LogInterceptionCheck struct {
    regexp      *regexp.Regexp
    Pattern     string
    Description string
}

func NewLogInterceptor(checks ...LogInterceptionCheck) *LogInterceptor {
    for i := 0; i < len(checks); i++ {
        each := checks[i]
        compiled, e := regexp.Compile(each.Pattern)
        if e != nil {
            log.Fatalf("cannot compile regexpt [%s]: %s", each, e)
        }
        checks[i].regexp = compiled
    }
    return &LogInterceptor{os.Stderr, checks}
}

func (interceptor *LogInterceptor) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    i, err := interceptor.target.Write(p)
    // use loop because it is faster and generates less garbage compared to for-range loop
    for i := 0; i < len(interceptor.checks); i++ {
        check := interceptor.checks[i]
        if check.regexp.Match(p) {
            _, e := fmt.Fprintf(interceptor.target, ">>>> Printing stacktrace [%s]\n", check.Description)
            if e != nil {
                log.Fatalf("cannot write: %s", e)
            }
            _, e = interceptor.target.Write(debug.Stack())
            if e != nil {
                log.Fatalf("cannot write stacktrace: %s", e)
            }
            break
        }
    }
    return i, err
}
```